# ssh reverse mysql tunnel with a aliased host

Tags: mysql, ssh

I am trying to ssh into my server and then access the mysql on localhost for quick prototype development when testing on live.

Here is my connection in the server:

```
mysql -h db_master_www -u game -D db_www -p
```

I then setup my tunnel (`sp` is my ssh config name)

```
~ssh -N -L 3336:db_master_www:3306 sp
```

And on my local machine

```
hutber@hutber:~$ mysql -h db_master_www -u game -D db_www -p
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'db_master_www' (-2)
```

So logically I'll need to use my host as the ip and not the alias?

Comment: This question is quite good but it would be better for https://serverfault.com/ where they could have helped you much better than here.

Comment: Thanks Javier! I shall look that up. Though Bill did answer the question for me within a few minutes thankfully!

Comment: The truth is that you were lucky, I would leave this question but I was removed a similar one but with fstab and I removed it, so I just tell you, in fact better leave it or change it to that page as you see it friend :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use an ssh tunnel to map the local port 3336 to the remote port 3306, you would connect to 3336 locally:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3336 -u game -D db_www -p
```

Make sure to use 127.0.0.1, not "localhost" because to the MySQL client, these are not the same.

Comment: Ah so my misunderstanding is that I am only mapping the ports, nothing else! I see!

Comment: So changing the hosts on both the tunnel and when connecting on my local machine results in the same error:
`hutber@hutber:~$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u game -D db_www -p
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (111)` I wonder if my auth is off.

Comment: Did you see the part in the example I gave where I specified the local port with `-P 3336`? The ssh tunnel is not listening on port 3306, it's listening on port 3336, according to your ssh command. So naturally you can't connect to 3306 on your local computer.

Comment: Since you don't seem to have a MySQL instance running on your local host, you are not required to use a distinct port 3336 when you create the ssh tunnel. You could use `ssh -N -L 3306:db_master_www:3306 sp` and then you wouldn't need to remember to specify the custom port to the mysql client.